# Im trying to count the longest sequence in an int array that sums to a non-negative(JAVA)...array is in the range -1,0,1

Tags: java, arrays

```
class SolutionJ 

{

    public int solution(int[] A) {
        int sum =0;
        int count=1;
        int max =0;

        for(int i=0; i<A.length-1; i++){
            if(A[i] + A[i+1] >=0){

                int temp = A[i]+A[i+1];
                sum += temp;
                count ++;

                for(int p=i+2; p<A.length; p++){
                        while(sum>=0){
                            sum+=A[p];
                            count++;
                    } if(count>max){max = count;}
                }
            } 
                else {
                continue;
            }
        }  
        return max;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SolutionJ cake = new SolutionJ();
        int [] bap = {1,0,1,1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,-1};
        System.out.println(cake.solution(bap));

    }

}
```

Trying to find the longest sequence in the array whose elements sum to 0 or more. When i attempt this i get result 0, I cant figure out what Im doing wrong, any assistance much appreciated. I figured total the first two elements(or move on) and then run a loop from the third element on, keeping track of the sum, and adjust the counter up when sum remains positive.

Comment: You don't change the value of `p` inside your `while` loop. So you're just adding `1` to `sum` until `count` overflows into the negatives.

Comment: Even if you fix that mistake though, your approach won't find the longest sub array that sums to `>=0`. You're finding the longest sub array where all prefixes of the sub array sum to `>=0`.

Comment: thanks man...back to the drawing board....cheers....

Answer (score 0):

This might be something you're looking for. Do note that this only works for integers ranging from -1 to 1. If you want it to work for any integer, then declare maxSoFar to be Integer.MIN_VALUE instead of -2.

```
public static int solution(int[] A) {
  int maxSoFar = -2, maxEndingHere = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    maxEndingHere += A[i];
    if (maxSoFar < maxEndingHere) {
      maxSoFar = maxEndingHere;
    }
    if (maxEndingHere < 0) 
      maxEndingHere = 0;
    }
  return maxSoFar;
}
```